# Schengen visa- I transferred funds from my savings account to current account for the visa. Should I explain in the cover letter?

Tags: schengen

This can be seen clearly from both accounts at the same banks, that the source of the funds is my savings account.
Should I write a cover letter to explain this? Both my accounts are linked.

Answer (score 1):

It can't possibly hurt to mention, and might help avoid confusion, so it sounds like a good idea.

However, formatting this note as a "cover letter" (with all the various trapping of letter layout, salutations at the top and signatures at the bottom, etc. etc.) would seem to be overkill. The consulate are not out to judge your eloquence or even your polite boilerplate -- just to spend as little time as the have to to get an overview of your economic situation.

You should be supplying a numbered list of the documents you enclose with the application in any case. If there's just that single transaction you think deserves explanation, you can pit it as a note right in the document list.

If there are several transactions you have comments on, you can attach a separately sheet with your notes to the bank statements, as an enclosure with its own number. Make it **skimmable**, in list format -- short and to the point, rather than long paragraphs of prose.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it's just one transaction mainly, because most of my funds I keep in my savings A/C, and transfer to current to cover smaller expenses from time to time. I might put a sticky note on the statement where the transaction appears to make it clear that it is from my savings A/C, and it says on the statement "From A/C XXXXX" (the savings account number).

Comment: @Shell9: It would be wary of depending on the _position_ of a sticky note to communicate your message. It only takes one person removing the sticky note temporarily (because they want to read/inspect/scan the original document) without examining the writing on it in enough detail to realize that the position matters ...

Comment: I see what you mean. I'll put in a sheet as well as the sticky note to ensure that they don't miss it. I want to ensure that they know that I simply transferred funds from my savings to current a/c, and that the funds haven't been borrowed from elsewhere, etc.

Comment: @Shell9 Honestly, a transfer between accounts should be completely obvious, even with the most cursory of glances

Comment: I suppose I just don't want to take a risk, considering it's VFS that accepts the application and not the Consulate.